# C# Get User Input Mask?

Tags: c#, regex, string, list, mask

I am using C# and i Want to read some data that separated with some characters

for example : "IP@DOMAIN;USERNAME:PASSWORD"

but it's different in each list that user give

so i want to try to get the mast with a mask list the example

i use something like this to read the list

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("PathToTheList");
foreach(string line in lines){reading line with mask}
```

Comment: If you know separated characters for each list you can use [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) or you can use regexp **[a-zA-Z]+** to retrieve all sequences of letters

Comment: Please add sample input, expected output and your attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved with the following regex:

```
"^([^@]+)@([^;]+);([^:]+):(.+)$"
```

- `^` assert position at the start of the string

  - `([^@]+)`
    capturing group for one or more characters, excluding '@' character (IP)
  - `@` match '@' character
  - `([^;]+)` capturing group for one or more characters, excluding ';' character (DOMAIN)
  - `;` match ';' character
  - `([^:]+)` capturing group for one or more characters, excluding ':' character (USERNAME)
  - `:` match ':' character
  - `(.+)` capturing group for one or more characters (PASSWORD)
- `$` assert position at the end of the string

---

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^([^@]+)@([^;]+);([^:]+):(.+)$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("PathToTheList");
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    Match match = regex.Match(line);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
        // group[0].ToString() == line
        string ip = groups[1].ToString();
        string domain = groups[2].ToString();
        string username = groups[3].ToString();
        string password = groups[4].ToString();
    }
}
```